# keydown no longer working after adding a ribbon control to a wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, events, ribbon, keydown

I have a strange problem, I had a WPF (with C# code behind) page with some buttons and some keydown events. Recently I've added a ribbon control to group the buttons and the keydown events aren't working any more.
The strangest thing is that if I add back any of the old buttons (outside of the ribbon) and click on it then the keydown events start working.

Thanks

```
<Page x:Class="Ab3d.PowerToys.Samples.SceneEditor.SceneEditor"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:cameras="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Cameras;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"
      xmlns:ab3d="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Controls;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"  
      xmlns:visuals="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Visuals;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"        
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ab3d.PowerToys.Samples.SceneEditor"       
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="550" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="SceneEditor" KeyDown="MainViewport_KeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown" 
      ShowsNavigationUI="False" >

    <Page.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityOfBool" />
        <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="Material1" Brush ="Coral"      />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Grid Name="OptionsGrid" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- THE RIBBON -->
            <ribbon:Ribbon SelectedIndex="0" KeyDown="MainViewport_KeyDown">

                <!-- Tab -->
                <RibbonTab Header="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000">

                    <!-- Draw --> 
                    <RibbonGroup Header="Draw" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
                        <RibbonButton x:Name="Point" 
                                      Label="Point"                                        
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\PointRo.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="20"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="NewLine" 
                                      Label="Line"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\NewLine2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="20"
                                      Click="NewLineButton_Click"/>

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="Arc" 
                                      Label="Arc"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Arc2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="20"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="Surface" 
                                      Label="Surface"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Surface2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="20"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="Volume" 
                                      Label="Volume"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Volume2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                        <StackPanel>
                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Clothoid"                                        
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Clothoid2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="22"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Spline"                                        
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Spline2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="25" 
                                      Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="22"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Ellipse"                                        
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Ellipse2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="24" 
                                      Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="22"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>


                    </RibbonGroup>

                    <!-- Transform --> 
                    <RibbonGroup Header="Transform" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140">

                        <StackPanel>
                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Move"  
                                      Label="Move"    
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Move.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Copy"  
                                      Label="Copy"    
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Copy3.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="30" 
                                      Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Rotate"  
                                      Label="Rotate"    
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Rotate2.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Mirror"  
                                      Label="Mirror"    
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Mirror.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Scale"  
                                      Label="Scale"    
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Scale.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="30" 
                                      Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                            <RibbonButton x:Name="Array"  
                                      Label="Array"    
                                      SmallImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Array.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="60"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel> 


                    </RibbonGroup>


                    <!-- Loads --> 
                    <RibbonGroup Header="Loads" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160">

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="Nodal" 
                                      Label="Nodal"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\NoadalLoads.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="50"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="UDL" 
                                      Label="UDL"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\UDL.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="50"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                        <RibbonButton x:Name="Face" 
                                      Label="Face"  
                                      LargeImageSource="C:\Users\Infra-Iordanescu\source\repos\ARES\Images\Face.png"                                      
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Height="60" 
                                      Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Width="45"
                                      Click="NewPointButton_Click"/>

                    </RibbonGroup>


                    <RibbonGroup Header="Analysis" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                    <RibbonGroup Header="Results" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                    <RibbonGroup Header="View" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                </RibbonTab>
                <RibbonTab Header="Prop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="798"/>
            </ribbon:Ribbon>




            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0 0 0">


                 <!-- <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Name="ResetCameraCenterButton" Content="Reset camera" ToolTip="Sets camera TargetPosition to (0,0,0)" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ResetCameraCenterButton_Click" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <Button Name="FitViewButton" Content="Fit to view" Click="FitViewButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 5 5 0" />
                </StackPanel> --> 


            </StackPanel>

             <!-- <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 0 0 0">
                <Button Name="newPoint" Content="Point" ToolTip="New Point" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="NewPointButton_Click" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                <Button Name="newLine" Content="Line" ToolTip="New Line (L)" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="NewLineButton_Click" Margin="0 5 5 0"/>
            </StackPanel> --> 


        </Grid>

        <Border Name="ViewportBorder" Grid.Row="1" Background="White"
                MouseMove="ViewportBorder_MouseMove" >



            <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport">
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="VisualSpace" />



                <visuals:WireGridVisual3D x:Name="MainWireGrid" 
                                          CenterPosition="0 0 0" 
                                          Size="200 200" 
                                          WidthCellsCount="25" 
                                          HeightCellsCount="25" 

                                          LineColor="#555555" 
                                          LineThickness="1"

                                          MajorLinesFrequency="5"
                                          MajorLineThickness="2"
                                          MajorLineColor="#333333"

                                          IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SceneEditorContext.Current}, Path=ShowWireGrid}" />

                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="ObjectsVisual" />
            </Viewport3D>
        </Border>







        <cameras:TargetPositionCamera Name="Camera1" Grid.Row="1" 
                                      TargetPosition="0 0 0" 
                                      Heading="30" Attitude="-30" Bank="0" 
                                      Distance="300" 
                                      ShowCameraLight="Always" 
                                      TargetViewport3D="{Binding ElementName=MainViewport}"/>

        <ab3d:MouseCameraController Name="MouseCameraController1" Grid.Row="1"
                                    ShowRotationCenterMarker="True"
                                    ZoomMode="MousePosition"
                                    RotateCameraConditions="RightMouseButtonPressed" 
                                    MoveCameraConditions="MiddleMouseButtonPressed" 
                                    EventsSourceElement="{Binding ElementName=ViewportBorder}" 
                                    TargetCamera="{Binding ElementName=Camera1}" />

        <ab3d:CameraAxisPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              TargetCamera="{Binding ElementName=Camera1}"
                              Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SceneEditorContext.Current}, Path=ShowCameraAxis, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}"/>

        <ab3d:ViewCubeCameraController Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       TargetCamera="{Binding ElementName=Camera1}"
                                       Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SceneEditorContext.Current}, Path=ShowViewCubeCameraController, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}" />

        <ab3d:MouseCameraControllerInfo Name="MouseCameraControllerInfo1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 5 0 0"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        MouseCameraController="{Binding ElementName=MouseCameraController1}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SceneEditorContext.Current}, Path=ShowMouseCameraControllerInfo, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}" />

        <!-- Selection canvas -->
        <Canvas Name="SelectionOverlayCanvas" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <Rectangle Name="SelectionRectangle" Fill="#555FD3FF" Stroke="#AA5FD3FF" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Canvas>

        <!-- Point data tooltip -->
        <Canvas Name="DataToolTipCanvas" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <Border Name="DataToolTipBorder" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightGray" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Coordinates:" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding X, StringFormat={}X:{0:N}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y, StringFormat={} Y:{0:N}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Z, StringFormat={} Z:{0:N}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
 private void MainViewport_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyDown");
            // ESC deselects all
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {                
                for (var i = 0; i < spheres.Count; i++)
                {
                    spheres[i].Material = material;
                    spheres[i].Radius = originalRadius;
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
                {
                    lines[i].LineColor = originalLineColor;
                }

                DataToolTipBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                this.DataContext = null;
            }
```

Comment: Can you add to your MainViewport_KeyDownm, this.OnKeyDown and check if it works? Seems that the Ribbon is doing some e.Handled = true

Comment: Hello Nekeniehl, I'm not sure where exactly to add the this.OnKeyDown?

Comment: Just do it under the System.Diagnostics.Debug line, before the if just to check if it works as I have this problem before and it was because the control was handling the key (e.handled)

Comment: I've added this.OnKeyDown(e); after the System.Diagnostics (not sure if I did it correctly). And it doesn't work. Even so, when debugging it never even steps in the MainViewport_KeyDown method.

Comment: How about using PreviewKeyDown instead? That way you can capture the event before other controls handle it.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain how should I implement it? In wpf there is already implemented a PreviewKeyDown and in C# there is declared a method for it, but in the way it is used now it never steps in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, by:

`Loaded="Page_Loaded"  Focusable="True"`

and

`private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Focus();
        }`

It seems it was a focus issue.
Thanks.